# stored procedure insert into select

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I do the following in oracle?

```
execute stored_procedure (column1, column2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM test
```

Basically, I want to select from a table and pass those rows to oracle stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a loop to loop through the records in your select statement and for each record call the procedure:

```
    begin
        for rec in (select col1, col2 from test)
        loop
            stored_procedure(rec.col1, rec.col2);
        end loop;
    end;
    /
```

A `FOR LOOP` such as this is probably the simplest approach.